# jasmine + angular + ng-include ... partials not rendering

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

my directive will include a partial based on a variable.

```
div(    ng-if='contactAgentCtrl.type === "slim-card"'
        ng-include='::"app/components/contact/agent/partial/slim-card.html"')

div(    ng-if='contactAgentCtrl.type === "form"'
        ng-include='::"app/components/contact/agent/partial/form.html"')
```

the element in my unit test only shows the above result and does not seem to render the partial content.  i've made sure the variable is set so it seems that it should include the partial.

i've also checked the $templateCache and both entries do exist.

here is my simple unit test:

```
  beforeEach(inject(() => {

  $scope = $rootScope.$new();

  $scope.type = 'form';

  $element = angular.element('<mre-contact-agent type="type"></mre-contact-agent>');

  $compile($element)($scope);

  directive = ContactAgent.factory()();

  $scope.$digest();
  }));
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue was the variable needed to be interpolated.

```
$element = angular.element('<mre-contact-agent type="{{ type }}"></mre-contact-agent>');
```